# How to implement From<Foo<U>> for Foo<T>

Tags: generics, rust, type-conversion, traits

I want to implement `From` for instantiations of a generic type in cases where the type parameters can be converted.

```
struct Item<T>(T);

impl<T, U> From<Item<U>> for Item<T> where T: From<U> {
    fn from(other: Item<U>) -> Item<T> {
        Item(other.0.into())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Item(10i8);
    let b: Item<i32> = a.into();
}
```

This fails with

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::From<Item<_>>` for type `Item<_>`:
 --> src/main.rs:4:1
  |
3 | impl<T, U> From<Item<U>> for Item<T> where T: From<U> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is already implemented by std

Comment: @Stargateur: What do you mean? If it's implemented, how do I call it? Removing my implementation results in another error: [the trait bound `Item<i32>: std::convert::From<Item<i8>>` is not satisfied](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=910e7aaf828f02adffd36f14ac602ad5)

Comment: It's not though. This touches specialisation and higher kinded types I believe. First one is unstable and latter one is not supported as of yet. Rust resolves this problem using some hacky way involving SpecExtend trait in vec for example. https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#1904-1907

Comment: Your implementation is conflicting with the `From<T> for T` implementation from `core` because it also covers `From<Item<T>> for Item<T>`.

Comment: @mcarton: Yes, that is correct.